# MS Service Fabric Installation Error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, failed-installation

I'm attempting to install MS Service Fabric SDK and Tools v2.4.145 (VS2015) and unfortunately the installation has failed.

Looking at the 8.5k log file provided, the appropriate section out of the log file I believe to be causing the problem is as follows:

```
InstallDrivers:  OpenService LeasLayr successfully.
InstallDrivers:  Ignore ControlService LeasLayr error code: 1052.
InstallDrivers:  Error 0x80070430: DeleteService LeasLayr failed with error code: 1072.
InstallDrivers:  Driver Path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\LeasLayr.sys 

InstallDrivers:  Error 0x80070430: CreateService LeasLayr failed with error code: 1072.
InstallDrivers:  Error 0x80004005: InstallDriver LeasLayr returned error 2147943472
CustomAction InstallDrivers returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (FC:54) [14:55:42:359]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (FC:54) [14:55:42:359]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 14:55:42: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to try and resolve this installation problem?

I have tried running as Administrator, installing prior versions, installing MS Azure SDK first, and even tried restarting my machine but with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Could you check the status of the service?  run command: sc query leaslayr

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem some months ago and recently had the time to investigate further which was when I found the same error as yours in the installation event log.

After a bit of searching on my local drive, I saw that "leaslayr" is actually a driver component and not a registered service in the Services management console, this got me looking at the installed drivers in the Device Manager.

After doing the following steps I was then able to install the Service Fabric SDK from Web PI.

> Step 1: Open Device Manager (devmgmt.msc in Start Menu, or via Run)
>
> Step 2: Expand System Devices
>
> Step 3: Find "Windows Fabric Lease Layer"
>
> Step 4: Right Click -> Uninstall
>
> Step 5: Restart
>
> Step 6: Perform installation again of Service Fabric SDK