# Unable to install MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-sdk

I am trying to install Azure SDK for VS2017 several times. I am following instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started .
I have installed Power Shell 5.0 but every time fails at same point. 
Here is screenshot.
[image]

Comment: This could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963201/ms-service-fabric-installation-error

Comment: I don't find "Windows Fabric Lease Layer" in Device Manager > System Devices, still unable install Azure SF SDK in Windows 7, VS 2017.